# cmdevicemotion stops providing update

Tags: ios, core-motion, cmmotionmanager

I have some weird issue in my code that I can't figure out and need some help.  I have defined a CMMotionManager in my AppDelegate.  In my view controller, I define a property:

```
    @property (nonatomic, retain) CMMotionManager *motionManager;
```

and then use this code to start the updates:

```
    - (void)startMyMotionDetect
    {
motionManager = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sharedManager];

motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0/60.0;

[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20/60 target:self selector:@selector(handleDeviceMotion) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

However, the handleDeviceMotion get called only a few time and then it stops updating the deviceMotion output.  I have changed the code to the push style (block code) but in that case the block is not getting executed!  A test NSLog comment in the block never gets executed.  Here is how that code looks like:

```
motionManager = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sharedManager];

motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0/60.0;

[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *dMotion, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"test 1");

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(handleDeviceMotion) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

 }];
```

Here is how the handleDeviceMotion code looks like:

```
- (void)handleDeviceMotion//:(CMDeviceMotion *)dMotion
{

if ([motionManager isDeviceMotionActive])
{
    NSLog(@"test");
}

....}
```

With the first method, I see "test" printed a few times and then it stops.

I thought by retaining motionManager as a property, I don't have to worry about it being released but it appears that it is getting released somewhere (or do you think something else is going on?).

Many thanks for your help.